# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 with knockout js I don't receive the data in the model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, knockout.js

I am new to ASP.NET CORE, I am sending the bindered data from knockout js and I do not receive it in my controller as I show in the following image,

[image]

I don't know why I don't get the model that I sent through knockout js, at the beginning I had a problem since the output of the data in JSON format is camelCase, but I solved it using the following command by adding it to the STARTUP,

```
services.AddMvc (). AddJsonOptions ( options =>
                 options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver ()
             );
```

implementing that command already gives me the output of the data in PascalCase, but I have a form with the bindadas properties and it does not send me data to the controller, this is the code of my form,

```
<div id="divCreateGenders" data-bind="visible: IsNew">
    <form id="FormCreateGenders" method="post">
        <div class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: GenderModel">
            <h3><strong>Crear Nuevo</strong></h3>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2"><strong>Codigo:</strong></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="TextboxGenderId" name="TextboxGenderId" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: GenderId" maxlength="1" placeholder="Por ejemplo, I" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2"><strong>Genero:</strong></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="TextboxGenderName" name="TextboxGenderName" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: GenderName" maxlength="15" placeholder="Introduzca un genero..." required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $parent.Create">Crear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code,

// Model
function genderModel() {
    var genderModel = this;

```
genderModel.GenderId = ko.observable();
genderModel.GenderName = ko.observable();
genderModel.CreateBy = ko.observable();
genderModel.CreationDate = ko.observable();
genderModel.ModifiedBy = ko.observable();
genderModel.ModifiedDate = ko.observable();
```

}

// ViewModel
function GenderViewModel() {
    var genderViewModel = this;

```
//Variables publicas//

genderViewModel.GenderModel = ko.observable(new genderModel());
genderViewModel.Genders = ko.observableArray();
genderViewModel.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
genderViewModel.IsBackToListButton = ko.observable(false);
genderViewModel.IsEdit = ko.observable(false);
genderViewModel.IsNewButton = ko.observable(true);
genderViewModel.IsDetails = ko.observable(false);
genderViewModel.ShowResult = ko.observable(true);
//Metodos Publicos//

genderViewModel.New = function () {
    genderViewModel.IsNew(true);
    genderViewModel.IsBackToListButton(true);
    genderViewModel.IsNewButton(false);
    genderViewModel.IsEdit(false);
    genderViewModel.IsDetails(false);
    genderViewModel.ShowResult(false);
    genderViewModel.Genders.removeAll();
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().GenderId(undefined);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().GenderName(undefined);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().CreateBy(undefined);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().CreationDate(undefined);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().ModifiedBy(undefined);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().ModifiedDate(undefined);
    $('#TextboxGenderId').focus();

};

genderViewModel.Delete = function (model) {
    swal({
        title: "Esta seguro?",
        text: "Que desea eliminar este genero?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        confirmButtonText: "Si",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/AdminGenders/Delete',
                    data: ko.toJSON(model),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.Success) {
                            genderViewModel.LoadAll();
                            swal("Eliminado!", "Se ha elimanado el genero satisfactoriamente", "success");
                        }
                        else {
                            swal("Error eliminando el genero!", data.Data, "error")
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                swal("Cancelado!", "El genero no ha sido elimanado", "error");
            }
        });
};

genderViewModel.Details = function (model) {
    genderViewModel.IsNew(false);
    genderViewModel.IsNewButton(false);
    genderViewModel.IsBackToListButton(true);
    genderViewModel.IsDetails(true);
    genderViewModel.ShowResult(false);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().GenderId(model.GenderId);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().GenderName(model.GenderName);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().CreateBy(model.CreateBy);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().CreationDate(model.CreationDate);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().ModifiedBy(model.ModifiedBy);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().ModifiedDate(model.ModifiedDate);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/AdminGenders/Detail',
        data: ko.toJSON(model),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success) {
            }
            else {
                alert(data.Data);
            }
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            swal("Error mostrando el genero!", "Ha ocurrido un error mientras se mostrando el genero!", "error")
        }
    });

};

genderViewModel.Edit = function (model) {
    genderViewModel.IsNewButton(false);
    genderViewModel.IsBackToListButton(true);
    genderViewModel.ShowResult(false);
    genderViewModel.IsDetails(false);
    genderViewModel.IsNew(false);
    genderViewModel.IsEdit(true);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().GenderId(model.GenderId);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().GenderName(model.GenderName);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().CreateBy(model.CreateBy);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().CreationDate(model.CreationDate);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().ModifiedBy(model.ModifiedBy);
    genderViewModel.GenderModel().ModifiedDate(model.ModifiedDate);
    $('#TextboxGenderId').focus();
};

genderViewModel.Create = function () {
    if (genderViewModel.IsNew()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/AdminGenders/Create',
            data: ko.toJSON(genderViewModel.GenderModel()),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    $('#TextboxGenderId').val('');
                    $('#TextboxGenderName').val('');
                    $('#TextboxGenderId').focus();
                    swal("Genero creado!", "Se ha registrado correctamente!", "success")
                }
                else {
                    swal("Error creando el genero!", data.Data, "error")
                }
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Ocurrión un error');
            }
        });
    }
};


genderViewModel.Update = function (model) {
    if (genderViewModel.IsEdit()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/AdminGenders/Update',
            data: ko.toJSON(model),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    genderViewModel.BackToList();
                    swal("Genero actualizado!", "Se ha modificado correctamente!", "success")
                }
                else {
                    swal("Error actualizando el genero!", data.Data, "error")
                }
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Ocurrión un error');
            }
        });
    }
};


genderViewModel.BackToList = function () {
    genderViewModel.IsNew(false);
    genderViewModel.IsBackToListButton(false);
    genderViewModel.IsEdit(false);
    genderViewModel.IsDetails(false);
    genderViewModel.IsNewButton(true);
    genderViewModel.ShowResult(true);
    genderViewModel.LoadAll();

};

genderViewModel.LoadAll = function () {
    LoadListGenders();
};


// Metodos Privados //
var LoadListGenders = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/AdminGenders/GetGender',
        data: null,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success) {
                genderViewModel.Genders.removeAll();
                genderViewModel.Genders(data.Data);
            }
            else {
                alert(data.Data);
            }
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Ocurrión un error, cargando los generos.');
        }
    });

};
```

}

```
jQuery(function () {
    var genderViewModel = new GenderViewModel();
    genderViewModel.LoadAll();
    ko.applyBindings(genderViewModel);
});
```

I don't know why it doesn't work because I have the same code working in ASP.NET MVC5, but I'm migrating to ASP.NET CORE and I have this problem, I'd appreciate the help

Comment: Could you please show the complete javascript code? I didn't see how you attach the `genderModel()` with `GenderViewModel()`.

Comment: Also, is your server controller annotated with a `[ApiController]`? seems that your server expects a payload of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while you send a `JSON`?

Comment: @itminus genderviewmodel I am doing the same to this model that I am using so it is this one, in addition to that I manually insert data to the database and if I load the data, it is not because I do not send the model to my controller , because I have that same code in asp.net mvc 5 and it works well I don't know why it doesn't work for me

Comment: If you don't want to show us the complete javascript code, please press F12 in browser and show us what payload is sent to server :) and also, please show us the controller class. As I said above, it looks like your server expects an `form-urlencoded` payload instead of JSON.

Comment: @itminus edit my code put all the javascript code i'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that your server expects a `form` payload while your javascript client sends a payload of `JSON`.

Since your js sends a JSON, if your controller has no `[ApiController]` attribute, please add a `[FromBody]` attribute so that the modelbinder knows the binding source:

```
// suppose your controller is not an ApiController
public async Task<JsonResult> Create([FromBody]Gender gender)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid){
        // ... model binding succeds
    }
    else{
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Or as an alternative, use `[ApiController]` if your controller is an ApiController:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/AdminGenders")]
public class AdminGendersController : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<JsonResult> Create(Gender gender)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Note in ASP.NET Core a controller that is annotated with a `[ApiController]` is different from plain Controllers. If your controller has a `[ApiController]`, the action methods by default expect a body of JSON. Otherwise, it expects a form.